# How to loop every 15 minute and get data from .txt at the same time?

Tags: vbscript

I have code like below for taking a data from .txt and loop every 15 minutes. I'm just experimenting with a value of 9000 to shorten time while testing. If successful I will set to 900000 for 15 minutes.

```
Dim fso, path, file, recentDate, recentFile, objFSO, objOutputFile, objTextFile, strText, i

i = 0
Do While i = 0
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set recentFile = Nothing
    For Each file In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\ID\Documents\DATA-DTL\vbs\").Files
        If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
            Set recentFile = file
        ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
            Set recentFile = file
        End If
    Next

    If recentFile is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo "no recent Files"
    Else
        'WScript.Echo "Recent file is " & recentFile.Name & " " & recentFile.DateLastModified
        Const ForReading = 1
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("temp.txt")
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("dtl.txt", ForReading)
        strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
        objTextFile.Close
        objOutputFile.Write strText

        Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("dtl.txt")
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp.txt", ForReading)
        strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
        objTextFile.Close
        objOutputFile.Write strText

        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ID\Documents\DATA-DTL\vbs\" & recentFile.Name, ForReading)
        strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
        objTextFile.Close
        objOutputFile.Write strText

        objOutputFile.Close
    End If

    WScript.Sleep (9000)
Loop
```

At the first the code runs, but in the loop I'm getting an error

> Name redefined 'ForReading'

Answer (score 4):

Move the `Const ForReading = 1` line directly below the `dim` statement at the top of your script.

As it says, you are trying to redefine a constant each time you go around the loop, which makes no sense.

Comment: Woah i see,
success to run and no error
thankyou so much!